# django save model ForeignKey relation

Tags: django, foreign-keys

in my model.py

```
class Layer(models.Model):
    user = models.IntegerField()
    name = models
    ...

class Point(models.Model):
    layers = models.ForeignKey(Layer)
    meta = models.TextField()
    ...
```

in my view.py

```
def datasave(request, id):
    mid = request.POST.get("layerid",default = "")
    metas = request.POST.get("meta",default = "")

    cs = Point()
    cs.layers = mid
    cs.meta = metas
    cs.save()
```

but it gives an error in my django debug..in my project i use geodjango,openlayers and extjs... i didnt find any solution about **saving my post**

i didnt make any relation with my foreignkey.. basically i want to make a layer than when i want to add a point in my layer , i want save my point with layer id....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's helpful to post the traceback to help understand your problem (for future questions).

It looks to me like you are passing in a number to your `Point` instance's `layers` attribute which would cause a `ValueError`. The only place you can pass a number to a foreign key field is in a django form which does the lookup for you.

You need to assign an actual `Layer` instance instead.

```
cs = Point()
cs.layers = Layer.objects.get(id=mid)
cs.meta = metas
cs.save()
```

Comment: thks for your help but when i did your solution it gave "featureadd() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)" how can i solve this?

Comment: My 1 line change would not cause that error. You could post the traceback for further help though!

Comment: i dont know what is meaning of traceback ... how can i take this

Comment: Either the error message in your server logs or the big error message screen you see when `DEBUG=True` that tells you exactly where your code failed.

Comment: it gave this error TypeError at /Layer/datasave
datasave() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
Request Method = POST....


in debug page ;
..../base.py

100.    response = callback(request, *callback_args,*callback_kwargs)

Comment: That means you didin't pass in an "id" argument from your URL to your datasave() view.

Comment: You need your url to capture an id, like `(?P<id>\d+)`, but since you're pulling ID from POST, just remove the `id` from your function definition.

Comment: oh man really thank you, when i look my database it was added but in my firebug it gave Internal Server Error and there is not any debug reply only written " The server encontered an internal error....

Answer (score 15):

A more efficient way is to specify the foreign key by adding an "_id" at the end, like this:

```
cs = Point(layers_id = mid, meta = metas)
cs.save()
```

DO NOT do layers=XXX.objects.get(id=###) because that's doubling the number of database queries.

ALSO ... you're not cleaning your POST data here, which is pretty dangerous. Get it like this:

```
from django import forms
id_field = forms.IntegerField()
layer_id = id_field.clean(request.POST.get("layerId", "")
```